# Task.Delay causes main task to abort

Tags: c#, async-await, task

My idea is to create a Task that will run at startup and continue to run while the main program runs. It will check periodically for some changes, create some tasks to do them and then wait again for the next check.

The code:

```
  private static async Task MainTask(CancellationToken token)
  {
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
        foreach (var client in StaticVariables.Clients)
        {
            Colors c = new Colors();
            Panel pnl = client.CreatePanel(c);
            client.SetPanelVehicle(pnl);
            client.RefreshPanel();
        }
        do
        {
            foreach (var client in StaticVariables.Clients)
            {
                tasks.Add((CheckClient(client)));
            }
            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
            tasks.Clear();
            //await Task.Delay(5000);
        } while (!token.IsCancellationRequested);
  }
```

Note the commented line `await Task.Delay(5000)`. Without it, it runs continuosly as I wanted, but adding that dealy causes it to exit the `MainTask` on the first occurence of it and never return.

How can I properly add that delay?

Comment: It should continue executing when the 5000 milliseconds is up, but the method *returned* at that point back to the caller. Can you show how you called this method?

Comment: You have added delay properly, but code which calls MainTask is not waiting for that delay

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I run this Task by calling `Task.Run(() => MainTask(cts.Token), cts.Token);` in MainForm `Load` event.

Comment: But do you await the task returned by Task.Run?

Comment: Wouldn't `Load` event body of `some code1 // await Task.Run(() => DiodesMainTask(cts.Token), cts.Token); // some code2` prevent the execution of `some code2` since this task bascially never completes?

Comment: Try the fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/e3GEjX - uncomment the commented out line to see how it affects the execution flow.
---
await Task.Run(...) _should_ prevent the execution of the next line.

Comment: Your commented out `Task.Delay()`; when it was aborting were you passing the `CancellationToken` to it?

Comment: I checked the token, it's properly false till the `MainForm_Closing` event when I set it to true and exit program.

Comment: Can you post a complete example of the core bits of your code that are causing this problem?

Comment: Maybe not the core problem but you seem to be doing lots of GUI stuff on a threaded Task. That's a no-go. Did you suppress the cross-threading check? Make sure that `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = true`

Comment: Create an [mcve]. I just ran a task like this w/o any problems.